# How do I uninstall a Service Worker?

Tags: html, google-chrome, service-worker

After deleting `/serviceworker.js` from my root directory, Chrome still runs the service worker that I removed from my webroot. How do I uninstall the service worker from my website and Chrome so I can log back into my website?

I've tracked the issue down to Service Work's cache mechanism and I just want to remove for now until I have time to debug it. The login script that I'm using redirects to Google's servers for them to login to their Google account. But all I get from the login.php page is an `ERR_FAILED` message.

Comment: I have the same issue in Firefox.

Answer (score 453, accepted):

#### Removing Service Workers Programmatically:

You can remove service workers programmatically like this:

```js
navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations().then(registrations => {
    for (const registration of registrations) {
        registration.unregister();
    } 
});
```

Docs: [getRegistrations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerContainer/getRegistrations), [unregister](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/unregister)

#### Removing Service Workers Through The User Interface

You can also remove service workers under the Application tab in Chrome Devtools.

Comment: I had to add "use strict"; before this code to make it work.

Comment: Is there anytime time-based around this? Say a user visited once, registered the worker, and hasn't come back since, do I need to keep this snippet in our codebase forever just in case?

Comment: How do I re-register service worker after unregistering it?

Comment: Verbose version: https://gist.github.com/mrienstra/9c60a76009480e2240770dadb2fb96fe

Comment: @Avery235 You would then need to add code back to your web page's script to register the new, hopefully not broken :), service worker.

Comment: I have a blog post reviewing this and other service worker remove/uninstall options https://love2dev.com/blog/how-to-uninstall-a-service-worker/

Comment: execute the code in the console。raise error，Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to get ServiceWorkerRegistration objects: The URL protocol of the current origin ('chrome-search://local-ntp') is not supported. cannot execute in the console？

Comment: @RichardChan `getRegistrations.then(...)` cannot be used on HTTP. Make sure you are on HTTPS before you call this function. E.g. check `location.protocol`.

Comment: To delete the service worker: copy the answer code into chrome console on the page where your service worker is

Comment: How would that help? The page is already cached by the installed worker and your new script will never be fetched by the users.

Comment: This code leads to an error in IE11. It doesn't support for..of. It's better to use for...in.

Comment: The following article discusses a potential issue with this answer's code and suggests an alternative: https://medium.com/@nekrtemplar/self-destroying-serviceworker-73d62921d717

Comment: The ServiceWorker is still active and running after calling ``registration.unregister()`. So this does not actually work like expected, does it?

Comment: Bump @sammy34's comment. For me, this approach didn't work but NekR's project worked. I wrote notes here: https://github.com/NekR/self-destroying-sw/issues/10#issuecomment-1312973827.

Answer (score 128):

You can also go to the URL: **chrome://serviceworker-internals/** and unregister a serviceworker from there.

Comment: You can type this into dev console to unregister all of them in one fell swoop.
`document.querySelectorAll(".unregister").forEach(item=>item.click())`

Comment: However, if you have other visitors that you need to unregister as well (friends, users, project managers, etc.), the answer above (by Daniel Herr) is more of an effective solution.  You've also got Firefox, Edge and Safari, as well, in flavors of iOS, Android, macOS, Windows 10 for each to test.

Comment: $$('.unregister').forEach(item => item.click())

Answer (score 51):

You can do this through **Chrome Developer Tool** as well as **Programatically**.

1. Find all running instance or service worker by typing

   > **chrome://serviceworker-internals/**

   in a new tab and then select the serviceworker you want to unregister.
2. Open Developer Tools (F12) and Select Application. Then Either

   > **Select Clear Storage -> Unregister service worker**

   or

   > **Select Service Workers -> Choose Update on Reload**
3. Programatically

```js
if(window.navigator && navigator.serviceWorker) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations()
  .then(function(registrations) {
    for(let registration of registrations) {
      registration.unregister();
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 24):

In Google Chrome, you can go to **Developer tools (F12) -> Application -> Service worker** and **unregister** the service workers from the list for that specific domain.

[image: Screenshot]

This method is effective in development mode of a site and mostly they run on `localhost` which is you may need for other project's development.

Answer (score 9):

FYI, in case you are using MacOS **Safari** browser, there is one way to forcibly unregister a service worker (steps and images for Safari 12.1):

1. Safari > Preferences... > Privacy > Manage Website Data…
   [image: Safari Preferences : Privacy]
2. Enter domain name (ex. 'localhost'), click "Remove"
   [image: Safari Preferences : Privacy : manage website data]

**Note:** In addition to service workers, this also will erase all caches, cookies, and databases for this domain.

Comment: Looks like this doesn't work if the service workers were installed via a Private Window.

Comment: @aris that's irritating giving Apple should be transparent, it is not even clear about the common websites' installed service workers.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the already correct answers given, if you want also to delete the SW cache you can invoke the following method:

```
if ('caches' in window) {
    caches.keys()
      .then(function(keyList) {
          return Promise.all(keyList.map(function(key) {
              return caches.delete(key);
          }));
      })
}
```

More [in this article](https://dev.to/paco_ita/service-workers-and-caching-strategies-explained-step-3-m4f) (Paragraph: "Unregister a service worker")

Another possibility, via Browser, is by accessing the "Cache Storage" section and click on the "Clear Site Data" button:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You should detecte two API in your devices: [getRegistrations](http://devdocs.io/dom/serviceworkercontainer/getregistrations) and [getRegistration](http://devdocs.io/dom/serviceworkercontainer/getregistration). The service-worker not has a unique set of APIs in all platforms. For example, some browsers only have a `navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration`, no `navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations`. So you should consider with both.

Answer (score 4):

IF your service worker don't let you update your files. You will need to replace serviceworker file (sw.js / ServiceWorker.js) with the next code:

```
self.addEventListener('install', function(e) {
  self.skipWaiting();
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function(e) {
  self.registration.unregister()
    .then(function() {
      return self.clients.matchAll();
    })
    .then(function(clients) {
      clients.forEach(client => client.navigate(client.url))
    });
});
```

[Source here](https://github.com/NekR/self-destroying-sw)

Answer (score 3):

**safely uninstall Service Worker**

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations().then(function (registrations) {
        for (const registration of registrations) {
          // unregister service worker
          console.log('serviceWorker unregistered');
          registration.unregister();
        }
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

to detect service worker:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.controller
```

Code to for deletion of service worker:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations()
  .then(registrations => {
    registrations.forEach(registration => {
      registration.unregister();
    })
  });

  navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations().then(function(registrations) {
   for(let registration of registrations) {
    registration.unregister()
  } })

  if(window.navigator && navigator.serviceWorker) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations()
    .then(function(registrations) {
      for(let registration of registrations) {
        registration.unregister();
      }
    });
  }

  if ('caches' in window) {
      caches.keys()
        .then(function(keyList) {
            return Promise.all(keyList.map(function(key) {
                return caches.delete(key);
            }));
        })
  }

  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations().then(function (registrations) {
          for (const registration of registrations) {
            // unregister service worker
            console.log('serviceWorker unregistered');
            registration.unregister();

            setTimeout(function(){
              console.log('trying redirect do');
              window.location.replace(window.location.href); // because without redirecting, first time on page load: still service worker will be available
            }, 3000);
          }
        });
      }
```

Answer (score 3):

as for me , i just use a new nonexistent scope service worker to replace old one,

```
ServiceWorker: {
        events: true,
        // what range of URLs a service worker can control. Use a nonexistent path to disable ServiceWorker
        scope: '/disable-service-worker/',
      },
```

as for the app.js, i add below code to unregister old sw:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations().then(registrations => {
    for (const registration of registrations) {
      // keep only serviceWorker which scope is /disable-service-worker/, The purpose is to make serviceWorker useless
      if (registration.scope.includes('/disable-service-worker/') === false) {
        registration.unregister()
      }
    }
  });
  // clear cache of service worker
  caches.keys().then(keyList => {
    return Promise.all(
      keyList.map(key => {
        return caches.delete(key);
      }),
    );
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If, like me, you need to unregister a service worker *after* deploying an entirely new codebase at the same domain (without a service worker), the solution is to create a new service worker at the same location and disable all caching:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', event => event.respondWith(fetch(event.request)))
```

This way, when the browser asks for sw.js (or whatever you named it), it will get the new one, then load your new site from the network. After an indeterminate time (i.e. after all your users have loaded the new service worker), you can remove the service worker.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers all add code to the live website to remove the service worker. However I didn't want to leave that live code running forever so I developed a solution that works from within the service worker itself. The steps are below, I posted more detail and explanation on [my blog](https://kevincox.ca/2020/11/03/removing-a-service-worker/).

1. Delete the code that registers the service worker.
2. Replace the service worker script with the following file. The new code must be available from the same URL the previous service worker was at. If you had multiple service worker URLs in the past you should duplicate the code at all of them.

```js
console.log("Cleanup Service Worker Starting");

caches.keys()
    .then(keys =>
        Promise.all(
            keys.map(async key => console.log("caches.delete", key, await caches.delete(key)))))
    .then(async () => {
        console.log("registration.unregister", await registration.unregister());
    })
    .then(() => console.log("DONE"))
    .catch(console.error);
```

This code is fairly straight forward. First it deletes all the caches, then it unregisters itself.

Users' browsers will automatically check for an updated service worker [the next time they load your website, or the next event 24h after the last service worker check](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API#Download_install_and_activate). This means that existing users will run this cleanup on their next visit.

Answer (score 2):

It can also be done in Chrome through application tab:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This code is compatible with Internet Explorer:

```
if (navigator.serviceWorker) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations().then(                
        function(registrations) {
            for (let idx in registrations) {
                registrations[idx].unregister()
            }
        })
}
```

IE doesn't support 'for...of' and 'for...of' construction may lead to "'SCRIPT1004: Expected ';'" error

Answer (score 1):

If You want to unregister all of the registered service workers in Browser,
you can do it by opening ex.

- Chrome: chrome://serviceworker-internals/
- Brave brave://serviceworker-internals/

open DevTools > Console and paste this:

```js
$$('.unregister').forEach(b => b.click())
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Brave. None of the provided answers worked for me on a page with a single service worker.

- `navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations()` stays pending.
- `navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration()` stays pending.
- `navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration(navigator.serviceWorker.controller.scriptURL)` stays pending
- `navigator.serviceWorker.ready` is fulfilled immediately unless there is no service worker registered for the current page

I used this:

```js
(await navigator.serviceWorker.ready).unregister()
```

Answer (score 0):

Open this page: **chrome://serviceworker-internals** and click to **unregister button**.

If you want to unregister all service worker open the **developer tools** and run this code on above page.

```
document.querySelectorAll("button.unregister").forEach(item=>{ item.click()})
```

Answer (score 0):

Open in Chrome

chrome://serviceworker-internals/?devtools

then F12 in Console 
$$('.unregister').forEach(b => b.click())

Answer (score 0):

Typical JavaScript loop thats compatible with everything:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations().then(function(registrations) {
    var registrationslength = registrations.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < registrationslength; i++) {
        registrations[i].unregister();
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can delete **all service** workers in **Chrome** in a second:

1. Go to chrome://serviceworker-internals
   or if using brave then go to brave://serviceworker-internals
2. In the console, enter the following code:

   $$('.unregister').forEach(b => b.click())

This code will click on the "unregister" button for each service worker, effectively deleting all of them :)