# How can I remove a buggy service worker, or implement a "kill switch"?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I'm playing with the service worker API in my computer so I can grasp how can I benefit from it in my real world apps.

I came across a weird situation where I registered a service worker which intercepts *fetch* event so it can check its cache for requested content before sending a request to the origin.
The problem is that this code has an error which prevented the function from making the request, so my page is left blank; nothing happens.
As the service worker has been registered, the second time I load the page it intercepts the very first request (the one which loads the HTML). Because I have this bug, that fetch event fails, it never requests the HTML and all I see its a blank page.

In this situation, the only way I know to remove the bad service worker script is through `chrome://serviceworker-internals/` console.
If this error gets to a live website, which is the best way to solve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 133, accepted):

I wanted to expand on some of the other answers here, and approach this from the point of view of "what strategies can I use when rolling out a service worker to production to ensure that I can make any needed changes"? Those changes might include fixing any minor bugs that you discover in production, or it might (but hopefully doesn't) include neutralizing the service worker due to an insurmountable bug—a so called "kill switch".

For the purposes of this answer, let's assume you call

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js');
```

on your pages, meaning your service worker JavaScript resource is `service-worker.js`.  (*See below if you're not sure the exact service worker URL that was used—perhaps because you added a hash or versioning info to the service worker script.*)

The question boils down to how you go about resolving the initial issue in your `service-worker.js` code. If it's a small bug fix, then you can obviously just make the change and redeploy your `service-worker.js` to your hosting environment. If there's no obvious bug fix, and you don't want to leave your users running the buggy service worker code while you take the time to work out a solution, **it's a good idea to keep a simple, [no-op](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP) `service-worker.js` handy**, like the following:

```
// A simple, no-op service worker that takes immediate control.

self.addEventListener('install', () => {
  // Skip over the "waiting" lifecycle state, to ensure that our
  // new service worker is activated immediately, even if there's
  // another tab open controlled by our older service worker code.
  self.skipWaiting();
});

/*
self.addEventListener('activate', () => {
  // Optional: Get a list of all the current open windows/tabs under
  // our service worker's control, and force them to reload.
  // This can "unbreak" any open windows/tabs as soon as the new
  // service worker activates, rather than users having to manually reload.
  self.clients.matchAll({type: 'window'}).then(windowClients => {
    windowClients.forEach(windowClient => {
      windowClient.navigate(windowClient.url);
    });
  });
});
*/
```

That should be all your no-op `service-worker.js` needs to contain. Because there's no `fetch` handler registered, all navigation and resource requests from controlled pages will end up going directly against the network, effectively giving you the same behavior you'd get without if there were no service worker at all.

### Additional steps

It's possible to go further, and forcibly delete everything stored using the [Cache Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache), or to [explicitly unregister the service worker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704791/how-do-i-uninstall-a-service-worker) entirely. For most common cases, that's probably going to be overkill, and following the above recommendations should be sufficient to get you in a state where your current users get the expected behavior, and you're ready to redeploy updates once you've fixed your bugs. There is some degree of overhead involved with starting up even a no-op service worker, so you can go the route of [unregistering the service worker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704791/how-do-i-uninstall-a-service-worker) if you have no plans to redeploy meaningful service worker code.

If you're already in a situation in which you're serving `service-worker.js` with HTTP caching directives giving it a lifetime that's longer than your users can wait for, keep in mind that a [Shift + Reload](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37562345/385997) on desktop browsers will force the page to reload outside of service worker control. Not every user will know how to do this, and it's not possible on mobile devices, though. So don't rely on Shift + Reload as a viable rollback plan.

### What if you don't know the service worker URL?

The information above assumes that you know what the service worker URL is—`service-worker.js`, `sw.js`, or something else that's effectively constant. But what if you included some sort of versioning or hash information in your service worker script, like `service-worker.abcd1234.js`?

First of all, try to avoid this in the future—it's [against best practices](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle#avoid-url-change). But if you've already deployed a number of versioned service worker URLs already and you need to disable things for *all* users, regardless of which URL they might have registered, there is a way out.

Every time a browser makes a request for a service worker script, regardless of whether it's an initial registration or an update check, it will set an HTTP request header called [`Service-Worker:`](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#service-worker-script-request).

Assuming you have full control over your backend HTTP server, you can check incoming requests for the presence of this `Service-Worker:` header, and always respond with your no-op service worker script response, regardless of what the request URL is.

The specifics of configuring your web server to do this will vary from server to server.

### The Clear-Site-Data: response header

A final note: some browsers will automatically clear out specific data and potentially unregister service workers when a special HTTP response header is returned as part of any response: [`Clear-Site-Data:`](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-clear-site-data/).

Setting this header can be helpful when trying to recover from a bad service worker deployment, and kill-switch scenarios are included in the feature's [specification](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-clear-site-data/#example-killswitch) as an example use case.

It's important to check the [browser support story](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Clear-Site-Data#Browser_compatibility) for `Clear-Site-Data:` before your rely *solely* on it as a kill-switch. As of July 2019, it's not supported in 100% of the browsers that support service workers, so at the moment, it's safest to use `Clear-Site-Data:` along with the techniques mentioned above if you're concerned about recovering from a faulty service worker in all browsers.

Comment: See also: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/2582

Answer (score 14):

You can 'unregister' the service worker using javascript.
Here is an example:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations().then(function (registrations) {
    //returns installed service workers
    if (registrations.length) {
      for(let registration of registrations) {
        registration.unregister();
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: This must be placed before the `.registe`  method, so that it will unregister all before to register or it can be run anywhere?

Answer (score 9):

That's a really nasty situation, that hopefully won't happen to you in production.

In that case, if you don't want to go through the developer tools of the different browsers, `chrome://serviceworker-internals/` for blink based browsers, or `about:serviceworkers` (`about:debugging#workers` in the future) in Firefox, there are two things that come to my mind:

1. Use the serviceworker update mechanism. Your user agent will check if there is any change on the worker registered, will fetch it and will go through the `activate` phase again. So potentially you can change the serviceworker script, fix (purge caches, etc) any weird situation and continue working. The only downside is you will need to wait until the browser updates the worker that could be 1 day.
2. Add some kind of *kill switch* to your worker. Having a special url where you can point users to visit that can restore the status of your caches, etc.

I'm not sure if clearing your browser data will remove the worker, so that could be another option.

Comment: Thanks for you answer.
Option 1 is not affordable for a live website.
I will take a look at Option 2, but I'm not very confident it would work if you registered your service worker on your website top level ("/")

Answer (score 4):

I haven't tested this, but there is an [unregister()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/unregister) and an [update()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/update) method on the ServiceWorkerRegistration object. you can get this from the navigator.serviceWorker.

```
navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration('/').then(function(registration) {
  registration.update();
});
```

update should then immediately check if there is a new serviceworker and if so install it. This bypasses the 24 hour waiting period and will download the serviceworker.js every time this javascript is encountered.

Answer (score 3):

For live situations you need to alter the service worker at byte-level (put a comment on the first line, for instance) and [it will be updated in the next 24 hours](https://slightlyoff.github.io/ServiceWorker/spec/service_worker/index.html#update-algorithm). You can emulate this with the chrome://serviceworker-internals/ in Chrome by clicking on *Update* button.

This should work even for situations when the service worker itself got cached as the step 9 of the update algorithm set a flag to bypass the service worker.

Answer (score 3):

We had moved a site from godaddy.com to a regular WordPress install. Client (not us) had a serviceworker file (sw.js) cached into all their browsers which completely messed things up. Our site, a normal WordPress site, has no service workers.

It's like a virus, in that it's on every page, it does not come from our server and there is no way to get rid of it easily.

We made a new empty file called sw.js on the root of the server, then added the following to every page on the site.

```
<script>
if (navigator && navigator.serviceWorker && navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration) {

    navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration('/').then(function(registration) {
        if (registration) {
              registration.update();
              registration.unregister();
        }
});

}
</script>
```

Comment: We had this on another site (same client they had sites on godaddy) - there is what I would call a bug in browsers. When the update mechanism gets a 404 on a service worker IT USES THE OLD ONE! So you need to make one.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps someone else, I was trying to kill off service workers that were running in browsers that had hit a production site that used to register them.
I solved it by publishing a service-worker.js that contained just this:

```js
self.globalThis.registration.unregister();
```

Comment: That might take 24h or more to work? But looks ok other than that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38843970/service-worker-javascript-update-frequency-every-24-hours