# ReactJS: Rewrite service-worker.js to hard reload

Tags: reactjs, service-worker

I have code on a production server which is using an old cached version of the `index.html` file. The only file it tries to dynamically load is the `service-worker.js` which no longer exists and thus gets back a `404`. Can a `service-worker` be re-written to force a hard reload when it is loaded?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [generic cache busting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/how-to-control-web-page-caching-across-all-browsers)

Comment: I have cache busting headers set now but unfortunately the old files were cached without these. The idea is to somehow rewrite the service-worker to force to browser to refresh all files. Not sure if that is even possible though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove a buggy service worker, or implement a "kill switch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33986976/how-can-i-remove-a-buggy-service-worker-or-implement-a-kill-switch)