# Service Worker cached root index.html

Tags: html, browser-cache, service-worker

I need to remove index.html from Service Worker cache. I have updated code, and removed html files from SW cache.

But old users who visited website before this new build are still loading SW Cached index.html which is not letting new SW to register. Hence page is still loading old index.html on visiting the domain name.

Any way I can resolve this. As of today, 11 Sep. Users are still viewing old index.html even after the new build which has the fix.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove a buggy service worker, or implement a "kill switch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33986976/how-can-i-remove-a-buggy-service-worker-or-implement-a-kill-switch)

Comment: This boils down to https://stackoverflow.com/a/38980776/385997. I'd recommend making sure that you keep the name of the service worker the same, but update its contents to make it a no-op.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could also just rename your index.html to index.htm and serve your updated service worker from there.