# Disable or remove service worker

Tags: service-worker, service-worker-events

Hi I would like to stop or unregister the service worker in my server. Upon checking our server through chrome browser its running a service worker. I would like to stop any execution of this script or stop it on the server itself. Is there any way to stop this **without renaming the service worker script** or having **additional called like unregister**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove a buggy service worker, or implement a "kill switch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33986976/how-can-i-remove-a-buggy-service-worker-or-implement-a-kill-switch)

Comment: check here hope you will get solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49740931/unregistering-removing-a-service-worker/49771828#49771828