# When should a service worker self destruct?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, offline, self-destruction

I found this repo describing [HOW to destroy a service worker](https://github.com/NekR/self-destroying-sw). But I didn't find any resources describing WHEN a worker should destroy/uninstall/unregister itself.

When I develop websites, I often use port 8080. I can be working on site X that has a service worker, then work on site Y that doesn't have a service worker but the original and now incorrect service worker persists.

The logic for a service worker deciding to uninstall itself is a bit tricky because we want to:

- Allow the service worker to work offline.
- Allow the service worker to survive a captive wifi portal.
- Detect the browser is online but this site should not have a service worker, or that the service worker should be a different one.

Is there a standard mechanism or convention around this?

Comment: https://redfin.engineering/how-to-fix-the-refresh-button-when-using-service-workers-a8e27af6df68  may help if u review that one

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer is that normally it would never destroy itself.

This seems to be a problem for you as you are developing multiple sites and then testing them all as `localhost:8080`.

Their are a few ways to address this particular problem:

The first would be to set up aliases for each site you develop in `/etc/hosts`.

```
127.0.0.1  local.site-a.com
127.0.0.1  local.site-b.com
```

Another option is to configure each project to run on a different port when testing.

The last option would be to include the code you linked to in your question, in each project that does not have a service worker. Although would this approach you would then ideally need to make your build process only include it in Dev builds.

Comment: I think a site that's in production might have a service worker, and a new version of it might not. In that case, it would be a pain to figure out and fix after the fact. That's why I can't accept this as an answer, it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: That is the use case for the script you linked to in your question

Comment: @ubershmekel Maybe you should edit your question to give a clearer context, if you don't accept the answer.

Comment: I asked "when should a service worker self destruct?" and this answer is claiming "never" or "manually". It would be a valid answer if it were absolutely the only way, but I believe there can be an automated self-destruct solution.

Answer (score 1):

you have to register a javascript file in serviceworker which checks the local path of site X before running your javascript file.

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/checking.js').then(function(registration) {
  // Registration was successful
  }
```

In checking.js

```
if(window.location.href == "YOUR X SITE FILE PATH"){
 //Run the javascript file which you have created for site X 
}
```

Remember during production you have to change the parameter of serviceWorker() to your respective js file

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `the parameter of serviceWorker()` and I'm not sure what in your answer would cause the service worker to trigger self destruction (`unregister` and refreshing the pages).

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers here it says that serviceworker will terminated when it is not in use. So by checking the local path of your site X you have to run service worker only then.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49740931/unregistering-removing-a-service-worker you can check this for unregister the serviceworker if you are using site Y or any else sites