# How to update service workers?

Tags: javascript, browser, service-worker, browser-cache

Situation:

On mywebsite.com/game, I registered a service-worker with

`navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js', {scope: "/"});`

On my server, `'/service-worker.js'` has a maxAge of `1d`.

---

Problem:

`service-worker.js` has a major bug. It always displays an empty page and can't fetch anything. `service-worker.js` must be changed.

The problem is whenever a user goes to `mywebsite.com/game`, it displays the empty page and does nothing more. I am unable to make the client fetch the new `service-worker.js`.

How can I make the client fetch the new `service-worker.js`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What you're describing—a check for updates to `/service-worker.js`—happens by default, automatically, under the circumstances laid out in [this article](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle#updates):

> An update is triggered if any of the following happens:
>
> - A navigation to an in-scope page.
> - A functional events such as push and sync, unless there's been an update check within the previous 24 hours.
> - Calling `.register()` only if the service worker URL has changed. However, you should avoid changing the worker URL.

All modern web browsers [will ignore any `Cache-Control` headers](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/06/fresher-sw) you set on `/service-worker.js` by default and go directly against the web server to obtain the latest copy.

This [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38980776/385997) has some best practices for what the revised `service-worker.js` file should contain if you want it to behave like a "kill switch."

Comment: Last verisions of chromium based browsers don't see any service worker file changes at all, versioning is the only reliable way to be sure that changes will be applied

Comment: That's not the intended behavior, and if you're seeing that in Chrome, it's very much a bug. You should provide details at https://crbug.com/new

Answer (score 0):

Just add ?v=1 to your script like this.

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js?v=1', {scope: "/"});
```

And increment the number of script version when you make changes of service worker's script

Comment: This doesn't work if the page is empty because of the previous service-worker.js.

Comment: This is bad practice when it comes to service workers. The uri should always be the same, e.g. '/service-worker.js'.