# Reload service workers and clear cache

Tags: javascript, reactjs, caching, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I have a React PWA with Service Worker, the problem is that I updated the project and the new project sort of cleaned the old project.
The problem is that the Page is still showing the old version of the project.
I know that the solution is to clear site data, or in other words. hard reload and empty caché.
Is there a way to clean caché with Javascript?

Comment: The info at https://stackoverflow.com/a/38980776/385997 should help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with nginx sending headers to clear browser cache. This problem was caused by an old index.html cached in the browser.
Information here:
https://serverfault.com/questions/549200/how-do-i-force-nginx-to-load-new-static-files