# I deleted a PWA but it still caches on mobile

Tags: .htaccess, caching, progressive-web-apps

I had a Progressive Web App that cached for offline use on mobile.

Recently, all the files were delete from the server and replaced with a temporary index.html holding page.

The problem I have is that the old PWA is still being cached on mobile. I have attempted to expire the cache in the .htaccess but this does not work.

Does anyone know how I can force remove this old PWA from a server level for all users?

Comment: Does the info at https://stackoverflow.com/a/38980776/385997 help?

Comment: Thanks @JeffPosnick, I looked at some of those solutions. And it appears there may have been an issue with my service worker caching. Anyway, I ended up putting the PWA back up and putting redirect content on all pages.