# How to remove a Service Worker from localhost?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I was exploring using Service Workers, but now every time I serve something up on localhost, I get Service Worker errors on Firefox. How do I remove a service worker?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I uninstall a Service Worker?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704791/how-do-i-uninstall-a-service-worker)

Comment: Those solutions don't work on Firefox.

Comment: Mozilla's own documentation states that it should work as of Firefox 44. [navigator.serviceWorker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/serviceWorker), [getRegistrations()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerContainer/getRegistrations), [registration.unregister()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/unregister)

Comment: I had to go to about: debugging and remove from there. That seemed to do the trick.