# Service Worker on Website before switching to website on new server

Tags: html, server, service-worker

We have just launched a website for a client on a new server. We have switched the DNS to our server.

However, it appears that there was a service worker and some client browsers are displaying text from the service worker that was hosted on the previous server.

How can this issue be sorted?

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I uninstall a Service Worker?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704791/how-do-i-uninstall-a-service-worker)