# Localhost port cannot be killed

Tags: ionic-framework, localhost, port, ionic-serve

I am using an Ionic app for a project and want to use http://localhost:8100/. Whenever I type
    ionic serve --port 8100 
it opens a previous ionic project that I used port 8100 for. In the CMD, I used the code 
    netstat -a -n -o
to list all of the ports used, but 8100 was not listed.

How can I get localhost:8100 to stop using my previous ionic app?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you had service workers enabled with the old ionic app so its serving up a cached version of your old app. Unregistering the service worker might help.

**[How do I uninstall a Service Worker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704791/how-do-i-uninstall-a-service-worker)**