# Registering a new service worker (file) and removing the old one (file)?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I have a website implemented in PHP that also has a service worker, i.e. `www.domain.com/sw.js` registered.

My intention is to rewrite the site entirely with NodeJS and what to rewrite the service worker with another file name, i.e `www.domain.com/service-worker.js`.

My doubts are:

- What happens if in the new implementation I stop serving the `sw.js` file? Does it makes the old service worker to be uninstalled and removed ? If not,
- How can I unsinstall the old service worker `sw.js` from the new one `service-worker.js`?

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove sw.js
2. Add service-worker.js
3. Use [this sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704791/how-do-i-uninstall-a-service-worker) to unregister any and all previous Service Workers
4. Register new SW at service-worker.js