# Service worker unregistered but still running

Tags: service-worker

I want to completely remove a service worker from my website that I initially put there without really thinking about it. I tried the `unregister` method from react-scripts v1.0.17 default `registerServerWorker.js` implementation:

```
export function unregister() {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
      registration.unregister();
    });
  }
}
```

In the Chrome dev tools, I see that the service worker is affected by the call to `unregister`: a  **'- deleted'** appears next to the hostname and the "update" and "unregister" links are greyed out. But the state is still "activated and is running". If I unregister it manually with the dev tools it disappears completely, like I would expect. This makes me think that the programmtic unregister command is failing or maybe not enough.

I tried looking up how to stop an SW programmatically but the examples only talk about unregistration. Can somebody shed some light on this?

Comment: You may consider providing the exact code you're using to unregister.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I uninstall a Service Worker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704791/how-do-i-uninstall-a-service-worker)

Comment: @cøder Your link is about how to unregister the SW. My question is about what happens in Chrome when I unregister the SW and how it differs from the results I get from the dev tools. So no, no duplicate.

Comment: Have you had any luck with this? I have the same issue

Comment: I've the same issue too. Worker is stil activated and running even if I unregistered it