# Removing local cache using server

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, caching, deployment, server

We just deployed our new website on the same domain but with a different stack. the old stack was create-react-app and it had service workers which is caching for offline usage.
Now after the new version is deployed, it still shows up the old version because of the cache. is there anyway i can force all users who visits the website to clear cache automatically?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I uninstall a Service Worker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704791/how-do-i-uninstall-a-service-worker)

Comment: @JoshLee no i'm not asking about uninstalling the service worker..i'm asking if it's possible to remove service worker cache from the new version's server? it's a whole new project