# gatsby-plugin-offline - how to disable the service worker for returning visitors if I've migrated to a new non-gatsby site?

Tags: service-worker, gatsby

We have just deployed a new non-gatsby site to replace our old gatsby site and have discovered that the old site had gatsby-plugin-offline enabled, so returning visitors using Chrome have a service worker running that is now displaying the 404 page from the old site.

What is the default time that this service worker will stay around for? Will this problem go away after 24 hours?

Is there anything we can do to resolve this for all returning visitors? I can see that the service worker is trying to retrieve page-data.json which doesn't exist. Can I create a version of that file that will override the service worker and force the new site to load?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I uninstall a Service Worker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704791/how-do-i-uninstall-a-service-worker)