# Nextjs remove workbox console.log messages

Tags: javascript, react-router, next.js, workbox

Any idea how to **disable** these console.log messages from `workbox` in a NextJS project?. I just started a new repo and it is just giving me too much information I don't need now[image]

Answer (score 30):

From the [next-pwa docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-pwa), **tips** section:

[image]

All you need to do is create `worker` directory in the root of your project and put `index.js` file in it:

```
// To disable all workbox logging during development, you can set self.__WB_DISABLE_DEV_LOGS to true
// https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/configure-workbox#disable_logging

// eslint-disable-next-line no-underscore-dangle,no-restricted-globals
self.__WB_DISABLE_DEV_LOGS = true;
```

Then restart the server - and there must be no logs in console.

---

I also find useful another option - completely disable sw during the development. You can do it with `disable` option in `next.config.js`, here is mine for example:

```
const path = require('path');
const withPWA = require('next-pwa');
const runtimeCaching = require('next-pwa/cache');

module.exports = withPWA({
  pwa: {
    dest: 'public',
    scope: '/',
    runtimeCaching,
    disable: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
  },
  sassOptions: {
    includePaths: [path.join(__dirname, 'assets/jss/vendor')],
  },
});
```

After server restart, sw will no longer receive updates, but you need to manually remove the old one:
[image]

Answer (score 10):

In Chrome's Console, select only the top context

[image: select by context]

And then, select this option to filter logs only by the active context

[image: filter by context]

Answer (score 5):

Looks like I registered a ServiceWorker pointing to my http://localhost:3000 while working on a PWA project back in the days.
I fixed this by removing (unregistering) the Service Worker from my Chrome Dev Tools `chrome://serviceworker-internals/?devtools`

First, I unregister my `localhost`
[image]

Second, I unregistered it from my chrome dev tools as well (I did it already that's why is not showing)
[image]

That was it, this question helped me
[How do I uninstall a Service Worker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704791/how-do-i-uninstall-a-service-worker)

Comment: I followed these steps but whenever I refresh the page, the service workers register themselves again and I am spammed with workbox console log messages. Is this just me?

Comment: I had this problem as well, but I fixed it by removing ServiceWorker (maybe investigate more about it) which was added when I was working with a PWA in NextJS. Good luck

Answer (score 4):

Setting the pwa mode to production disables console logging. try this:

next.config.js

```
// inside of next.config.js
module.exports = withPWA({
    pwa: {
      dest: 'public',
      mode: 'production'
    },
 });
```

This worked for me. Found this at : https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-pwa#user-content-tips

> Force next-pwa to generate worker box production build by specify the
> option mode: 'production' in your pwa section of next.config.js.
> Though next-pwa automatically generate the worker box development
> build during development (by running next) and worker box production
> build during production (by running next build and next start). You
> may still want to force it to production build even during development
> of your web app for following reason: Reduce logging noise due to
> production build doesn't include logging. Improve performance a bit
> due to production build is optimized and minified.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable logs by adding this:

```js
const withPWA = require('next-pwa')({
  // ...
  disableDevLogs: true,
  // ...
})
```

Comment: not working in my

Answer (score -1):

Those messages only show up in development. You can disable them.

```js
workbox.setConfig({ debug: false });
```

Or inside your `service worker` (make sure to do it before you use `workbox`)

```js
self.__WB_DISABLE_DEV_LOGS = true
```

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? Where should I add them? I added the first one in my next.config.js, but I got a `ReferenceError: workbox is not defined`

Comment: How and where are you loading the workbox script?

Comment: I created a new brand new NextJS project using `npx create-next-app my-project`