# How to fix ESLint Error when trying to remove service worker

Tags: javascript, eslint, service-worker

Based on this answer [How do I uninstall a Service Worker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704791/how-do-i-uninstall-a-service-worker)
Removing service worker can be done with the bellow code:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations().then(function(registrations) {
 for(let registration of registrations) {
  registration.unregister()
} })
```

When I add it. ESLint has the following error:

> error  iterators/generators require regenerator-runtime, which is too
> heavyweight for this guide to allow them. Separately, loops should be
> avoided in favor of array iterations  no-restricted-syntax

Any idea how to rewrite this code to make ESLint not complain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the code like this, and use `Object.entries/Object.keys/Object.values` depending on use-case with `forEach`:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations().then(function(registrations) {
 Object.entries(registrations).forEach(registration =>{
  registration.unregister()
}) })
```

Comment: Thank you this solution worked well. And I learned something new!

Answer (score 0):

From the [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/issues/1271#issuecomment-283424802) for the error you mentioned.

You could use any of the array iterators mentioned in the link.

```
registrations.forEach(function (registration) {
  registration.unregister();
});
```